# Python Message box not updating when class method is requested from a global instance request. What am I missing here?

Tags: python, tkinter, messagebox

```
import tkinter as TK
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

############################################
root = TK.Tk()
root.geometry("1000x700+1+5")
WindowTitle = 'Test MessageBox'
Revision = 'Support 1.0';

gServerData = 'Let there be Rock'


# COMMAND/Communication Message Window Test Button #############
def ButtonTest():
    global gServerData
    #gServerData = '128,TestingMojo'
    print('* ButtonTest Function: Ready to Print in MessageBox',gServerData)
    Api.PrintMessage()

# TABS Notebook page Setup 
class API_Tabs(TK.Frame):

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook()
        self.Tabs()
        self.notebook.place(x=5, y = 1, height=690, width =990)
        self.master.title(WindowTitle)
        #self.MessageHistoryText = MessageHistoryText

    #Setup ttk Notebook style 
    def Tabs(self):
        page1 = Api_Select(self.notebook)
        page2 = Api_Operations(self.notebook) 

        self.notebook.add(page1,text="Main")
        self.notebook.add(page2,text="Operation")   

############################################    
class Api_Select(Frame):
    def __init__(self,name,*args,**kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        self.name = name


class Api_Operations(Frame):
    def __init__(self,name,*args,**kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        self.name = name
        self.createWidgets()
        self.PrintMessage()

    def PrintMessage(self):
        global gServerData
        print('* Print Message Function: Message Ready',gServerData)
        self.MessageHistoryText.delete('1.0',END)
        self.MessageHistoryText.insert(TK.END, 'GlobalServer:' + gServerData + '\n', 'notice')
        self.MessageHistoryText.see(TK.END)
        self.MessageHistoryText.update()
        root.update()
        print('* Print Message Function: MessageBox Update',gServerData)

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.mainFrame = Frame(self) #TK.Frame(self)
        self.mainFrame.place(x=0, y = 0, height=650, width = 1000)

        self.ButtonTestPB = TK.Button(self.mainFrame, text='TEST', command= ButtonTest)
        self.ButtonTestPB.place(x=50, y = 100, height=50, width = 50)

        # COMMAND/Communication Entry Window and Send Button #############
        self.MessageFrame = TK.Frame(self.mainFrame)
        self.MessageFrame.place(x=240, y = 50, height=370, width = 360)
        self.MessageCmdLabel = TK.Label(self.MessageFrame, text= 'Command/Communications',anchor="w" )
        self.MessageCmdLabel.place(x=0, y = 0, height=25, width = 200)
        self.MessageHistoryText = TK.Text(self.MessageFrame, height=20, width=40, relief=TK.SUNKEN)
        self.MessageHistoryScroll = TK.Scrollbar(self.MessageFrame)     
        self.MessageHistoryText.config(yscrollcommand=self.MessageHistoryScroll.set)
        self.MessageHistoryScroll.config(command=self.MessageHistoryText.yview)
        self.MessageHistoryText.place(x=0, y = 25, height=300, width = 350)
        self.MessageHistoryScroll.place(x=350, y = 25, height=300, width = 15)      
        self.MessageHistoryText.tag_configure('warning', foreground='red', background='gainsboro')
        self.MessageHistoryText.tag_configure('notice', foreground='blue', background='gainsboro')  

App = API_Tabs(root)
Api = Api_Operations(App)
#_thread.start_new_thread(Receive, ("Receive_Thread",))
App.mainloop()
root.destroy()
```

''' Using the Button on the ops page should give me the same result as the statup text in the message box. This is a small example of a very large GUI. I have a thread running that calls a global function when data is received. This all works. What I need to do is have the received data print to my operations page message box without requesting it. The test button is to mimic the request.

But it is not working. Any Thoughts?
'''

Comment: Is it possible to reduce your code down to a [mcve]? There seems to be a lot of unrelated code. For example, if the problem is with a messagebox, is it really important to to have multiple tabs?

Comment: Yes. Too much codes here. Please list that you think where the issue is.

Comment: Because I am dealing with multiple tabs. I reduced it down to 2 and only the message box. I wanted the Page reference to simulate the messagebox write that fails when I press the button. this simulates the function call from outside the class. My program is 3000 lines and a lot of buttons for an automated robotic system. What you have here is pretty diluted

Comment: The code has a delete that is masking the problem. Remove this line  self.MessageHistoryText.delete('1.0',END) in the PrintMessage Function

Comment: You can ignore the API_Tabs and API_Select class as that gives the basic paging functions

Comment: # COMMAND/Communication Message Window Test Button #############
def ButtonTest():
    global gServerData
    #gServerData = '128,TestingMojo'
    print('* ButtonTest Function: Ready to Print in MessageBox',gServerData)
    Api.PrintMessage() ...does not print to message box. only to command window

Comment: bare with me this is my first attempt at a Python GUI and First Python app. So I am sure there will be a lot of shortcuts and methodology issues I am missing here. Not new to programming just Python and TKinter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run your code, click the button and see the `print()`s, so I don't know what is wrong. Your question says *"But it is not working"* but doesn't describe exactly how it is failing. The example provided seems to work fine and doesn't reproduce the problem?

Avoid using threads though - you don't need a thread to receive something from network, you can use tkinter's low-level `createfilehandler` to create an event that will be called when something is available to read in a socket, without freezing the gui and without threads. Or if you prefer higher level (recommended) You can use an asynchronous framework communication protocols!

EDIT: From the comments I can finally see what your problem is: **You have two instances of the `Api_Operations` class**.

One of them is being instanced and stored as the global variable named `Api`:

```
Api = Api_Operations(App)
```

The other is created inside the `API_Tabs` class, in the `Tabs()` method, and stored as a local variable named `page2`:

```
page2 = Api_Operations(self.notebook)
```

Since you are displaying `page2` but updating `Api`, the updates never show because the instance you're updating is not the one shown in the screen.

To fix it, store the instance you create in `API_Tabs.Tabs()` as an attribute:

```
def Tabs(self):
    page1 = Api_Select(self.notebook)
    self.Api = Api_Operations(self.notebook) 

    self.notebook.add(page1,text="Main")
    self.notebook.add(self.Api, text="Operation")
```

Then in your `ButtonTest()` function you can access it using the `API_Tabs` instance stored in the global name `App`:

```
App.Api.PrintMessage()
```

You can remove your `Api = Api_Operations(App)` line.

Comment: the message in the box is only appearing because it is initialized. I have Sockets running in my Application so a thread is running in the background to retrieve information and command data. The button press shows the print statements in the function but the message box should be scrolling down with every press

Comment: Remove the self.MessageHistoryText.delete('1.0',END) from the code and you will see the issue is that the message box does not update and scroll

Comment: @Michael I still believe you shouldn't use threads, you can use sockets without using threads using one of the methods I recommended in the answer. But now your problem is clearer, so I edited my answer to give you a solution. If you still have problems please tell.

Comment: Thank you for looking deeper into this and finding the problem. I am a little confused on the Tabs class on how to structure it with you revision. The .... makes it unclear what to add or delete and where

Comment: I will look into the handler method as opposed to threads. We were using a Hnadler method before but wanted to pull the SOCKETS retrieval out of the class and a Thread is what many of us here have used in the past. But I dont particularly like them either. Too easy to not destroy them and lock up the GUI

Comment: Thank you again for the help and your feedback

Comment: @Michael The `...` is the other pages you're adding to the notebook. I edited the code and included the entire method to make it clearer. If my answer is ok please consider marking it as correct to close the question.